# Review notification appears when the queue is empty

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

I was on the PPCG meta site, and suddenly the "3 notifications" appeared. I went there, and the queues are all empty. Refreshing and revisiting the page did nothing.

Is this perhaps showing me notifications for items in the queue that I had already reviewed? The notifications appeared *after* my most recent reviews.

[image]

Comment: That number is cached.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Cached where? It's not cached in my browser.

Comment: No. Server side.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Do you want to post an answer, or should I delete the question?

Comment: I'm sure there is a duplicate out there somewhere. Maybe someone will find it or provide an answer themselves.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I found one.